# creating x amount of elements in a link list

Tags: java, linked-list

I have a task of making a link list that has `5, 7, 3,5, 7, 3` elements and `5, 7, 3` is repeated 100 times

```
IntNode first = new IntNode() ;
first.value = 5 ; //first -> 5
first.next = new IntNode() ;
first.next.value = 7 ; //first -> 5 -> 7
first.next.next.next = new IntNode() ;
first.next.next.next.value = 3 ;
```

instead of just keep adding repeating elements next x amount of times, is there any way how I can use a loop to create the link list.

Comment: I am sure that your teacher mentioned something about loops, didn't he?

Comment: I am sure when they talked about linked lists, they also talked about how to keep a pointer which traverses the linked list.

Comment: The following link will help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236486/adding-items-to-end-of-linked-list

Comment: @gresdiplitude:  Doesn't really matter if it's homework or not anymore...  Anyway, to answer the question, **yes**, it's possible to use a loop.  Follow-up:  Do you have any sort of `insert()` method in your `LinkedList` class?  That's a really big hint there. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
    // IntNode first = new IntNode();
    // first.value = 5; // first -> 5
    // first.next = new IntNode();
    // first.next.value = 7; // first -> 5 -> 7
    // first.next.next.next = new IntNode();
    // first.next.next.next.value = 3;
    int values[] = { 5, 7, 3 };     
    IntNode first = new IntNode();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        IntNode temp = new IntNode();
        temp.value = values[i % 3];
        temp.next = new IntNode();
        first.next = temp;
        first = first.next;
    }
```