# Adding set to iterable list in java

Tags: java, set, iterable

So I have some Set, and I want to add the elements to a LinkedList so I can iterate over them. How would I go about doing this in java?

Comment: with code. with code. OR an internet search and then code.

Comment: `puslic static void main(String[] args)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taken from a question here: [Adding items to end of linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236486/adding-items-to-end-of-linked-list)

```
class Node {
    Object data;
    Node next;
    Node(Object d,Node n) {
        data = d ;
        next = n ;
       }

   public static Node addLast(Node header, Object x) {
       // save the reference to the header so we can return it.
       Node ret = header;
   // check base case, header is null.
   if (header == null) {
       return new Node(x, null);
   }

   // loop until we find the end of the list
   while ((header.next != null)) {
       header = header.next;
   }

   // set the new node to the Object x, next will be null.
   header.next = new Node(x, null);
   return ret;
   }
}
```