# How to add a node to the end of the linked list in a generic class?

Tags: java, generics, linked-list, queue

```
 class linkedqueue <item_t> {

   private class node{
    item_t item;
    node link;

     public node(item_t t, node l){
       item=t;
       link=l;

   }

   private node front = null;
   private node rear = null;

   public void insert (item_t any) {
      this.link=new node(any,this.link);

   }
```

the insert method should add "any" to the end of the queue. It works only in the node class, but now it is in the linkedqueue class, I don't know how to fix the "this.link" part..

Answer (score 0):

The last node in the LinkedList will point to a null value. So, grab the last Node in the list, set its next node to the new node you are passing in, and lastly set the new node's next pointer to null, indicating the end of the list.

```
private void addLast(Node<T> aNode)
{
    Node<T> head, lastNode;

    head = this.getHead();

    mySize++;

    if(head == null)
    {
        this.addFirst(aNode);
    }
    else
    {
        lastNode = this.getPrevious(null);  // get last Node, which is the Node previous to Null
        lastNode.setNext(aNode);  // add the new node to the end of the list
        aNode.setNext(null);  //set the new node's next pointer to null, indicating the end of the list
    }
}
```

Comment: be simple.. how to write "insert" method...which insert a node with value "any" to the end of the queue..

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to the linked list.. there are lots of methods in your code that i'm not sure what they're implemented..

Comment: Okay, I am glad I was able to help. Check out this link for additional information, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236486/adding-items-to-end-of-linked-list.