# How to add an element to the end of a linked list

Tags: java, list, stack

I'm trying to add an element to the end of a linked list but I'm not quite sure how to accomplish this. Here is the current code for the method I'm working with:

```
public void pushLast(T element) {
    LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);
    if (isEmpty()) {
        top = temp;
    } else {
        LinearNode<T> current = top;
        while (current.getNext() != null) {
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        current.setNext(temp);
    }
```

Does this look correct? Here is my entire code to go along with this method:

```
import java.lang.StringBuilder;

public class Murray_A05Q3 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        LinkedStack<Integer> stack = new LinkedStack<Integer>();


        System.out.println("STACK TESTING");

        System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString());

        stack.push(3);
        stack.push(7);
        stack.push(4);
        System.out.println(stack.peek());
        stack.pop();        
        stack.push(9);
        stack.push(8);
        System.out.println(stack.peek());        
        System.out.println(stack.pop());
        System.out.println(stack.peek());        

        System.out.println("The size of the stack is: " + stack.size());
        System.out.println("The stack contains:\n" + stack.toString()); 

    } // End of method header.


    public static class LinkedStack<T> implements StackADT<T> {

        private int count;  
        private LinearNode<T> top; // serves as node class


     // Creating an empty stack
        public LinkedStack() {
            count = 0;
            top = null;
            int pushLast;
        }

        @Override
        public void push(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);

            temp.setNext(top);
            top = temp;
            count++;
        }


        public T pop() throws EmptyCollectionException {
            if (isEmpty())
                throw new EmptyCollectionException("stack");

            T result = top.getElement();
            top = top.getNext();
            count--;

            return result;
        } 

        public void pushLast(T element) {
            LinearNode<T> temp = new LinearNode<T>(element);
            if (isEmpty()) {
                top = temp;
            } else {
                LinearNode<T> current = top;
                while (current.getNext() != null) {
                    current = current.getNext();
                }
                current.setNext(temp);
            }
        }


        public T peek() throws EmptyCollectionException {

            return top.getElement();    
        }


        public boolean isEmpty() {

            return (top == null);   
        }


        public int size() {

            return count;
        }


        public String toString() {


            if (isEmpty()) {
                return " ";
            }

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(top.toString());
            LinearNode<T> next = top.getNext();

            while(next != null) {
                sb.append("\n").append(next.getElement());
                next = next.getNext();

            }

            return sb.toString();

        } // End of the toString method.

    } // End of method header.

} // End of class header.
```

Note: just in case you want to run this yourself, I'm providing three files I have attached to the one above.

LinearNode:

```
public class LinearNode<T> {
    private LinearNode<T> next;
    private T element;

    public LinearNode() {
        next = null;
        element = null;
    }

    public LinearNode(T elem) {
        next = null;
        element = elem;
    }

    public LinearNode<T> getNext() {
        return next;
    }

    public void setNext(LinearNode<T> node) {
        next = node;
    }

    public T getElement() {
        return element;
    }


    public void setElement(T elem) {
        element = elem;
    }
}
```

EmptyCollectionException:

```
public class EmptyCollectionException extends RuntimeException {

    public EmptyCollectionException(String collection) {
        super("The " + collection + " is empty.");
    }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Way too much code, way too much whitespace. Condense your code to where you're having issues. Also, try something first ;)

Comment: Shouldn't there be some value inside pushLast method that's going to be moved to the bottom or no? I'm still trying to understand linked list.

Comment: Just checking that you are aware Java has a built-in LinkedList type (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html). If this is for production code, don't write your own.

Comment: This is a duplicate of this :http://stackoverflow.com/a/5236710/1990536

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>After adding your data item when the stack list has items in it, you don't reset the current member of your data structure, so you will probably have items in methods like `peek()`. It also looks like you don't reset your `current` node when the first item is added. Try this:</del>

Edit: I think I answered this one when I was too tired, and is incorrect.

Comment: You're using "current" in the first if block, but defining it later in the else block.  That shouldn't even compile.

Comment: Wow, I think I answered this one when i was too tired, edited.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming this is just a learning exercise to understand the inner workings of a linked list, otherwise, see Alex Taylor's advice above.

Your approach will work, but will get slower the longer your list grows.  If your class maintained a reference to the last element in the list, you could push in one step O(1) rather than visiting each element in the list O(N) before appending.

Another thing to think about is protecting your object from concurrent use.  If two threads were running your `pushLast` method at the same time on the same object, then they could both determine the same last member of your list as `current`, and one could overwrite the other's `next` value, losing data.  Look up `synchronized` in your Java manual.