# write a function to add to the end of linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I need help with the below. my below is my attempt but i am getting an error. I am getting an assertion error. This is a function in a class called playlistentry.java.  and i need to create a funtion to add to the end of the list.

```java
/**
 * 
 * @param song
 * add an instance copy (and not a reference copy) of the passed song to the end of the list
 * for example,
 * let the ID shown in Eclipse during debug mode 
 *      for p be 110, 
 *      for p.next be 115, 
 *      for song be 120 and 
 *      for song.next be 125
 * if p.title = "a", p.next.title = "b"
 * song.title = "c", song.next.title = "d"
 * 
 * p.addToEnd(song); 
 * 
 * should result in p.next.next.title = "c", p.title = "a", p.next.title = "b" 
 * and p.next.next.next = null (not the song "d")
 * also, the ID shown in Eclipse for p.next should NOT be 120. 
 * (because we are adding an instance copy)
 * 
 * upon executing
 * p.next.next.title = "e"
 * should result in p.title = "a", p.next.title = "b", p.next.next.title = "e"
 * 
 * song.title should still remain "c" (that's what it means by instance copy)
 */
public void addToEnd(PlaylistEntry song) {
        PlaylistEntry temp=song;
        if(temp!=null) {
            if(next!=null)  {           
                next=temp;
                next.next=temp.next;
                next.previous=temp.previous;
            }

            PlaylistEntry curr=next;

            while(curr!=null) {             
                curr=curr.next;
            }
            next=temp;
            next.next=temp.next;
            next.previous=temp.previous;            
        }
}
```

Comment: Please clarify *exactly* what error you're receiving, and show the code that's calling the method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding items to end of linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236486/adding-items-to-end-of-linked-list)